# Hot to search for the existence of 2 xml files in one if statement?

Tags: c#, file-exists

As the title suggests i am trying to write an if else statement that searches for the existance of 2 xml files ( and if they do exist the user will have the option of which one to load) but currently all i can do is an else if statement that assumes there is only one of the two files,

```
private void yourCharacterInformationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This will search for and load the saved name class from the relevant Xml file.
```

below is my code [Current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfYMm.png)

i couldnt find an answer allready on here after trawling through for a while, if someone could provide an answer that would be brilliant, again all i want to do is to search for the existence of 2 files in the same if statement such as

```
if(file.exists("ClassData.xml", "UserClassData.xml")
{
       messagebox.show("Which version do you want to load?").
```

Comment: if (file.exists(File1) && file.Exists(File2)){//DO STUFF}

Comment: `if (file.exists("test1.xml") && file.exist("test2.xml"))`

Comment: Note that file takes a capital F

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write compound if statements by using the [`&&`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) operator.

```
if (File.Exists("NameData.xml") && File.Exists("ClassData.xml"))
{
    // Omitted for brevity...
}
```

Both sides would need to be true in order to execute. The `System.IO.File` class method for `Exists` only accepts a single string. You could write a method that takes any number of file paths and call into this method like so (a little Linq):

```
private bool AllFilesExist(params string[] paths)
{
    return paths != null && paths.All(File.Exists);
}
```

Then you could invoke this method from within your call like so:

```
private void yourCharacterInformationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (AllFilesExist("NameData.xml", "ClassData.xml"))
    {
        // Omitted for brevity...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! this worked like a charm have a nice day